# Empty and isset not working for array input

Tags: php, validation

I'm having a issue for the validation of array input for empty
 value.
For e.g.

```
      if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {


if(empty($_POST['arrinput'])){
  echo 'value not empty';
    }
else {


  echo 'value is empty';
}
    }

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
  <?php
    $num = 0;
    while($num < 2)
    {?>
<input name="arrinput[]" type="text" /></div>
 <?php        $num++;
    }
 ?>
  <input type="submit" value="submiy"  name="submitted"/>
</form>
```

Any suggestion how can I accomplish this?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya it's not validating the empty value

Comment: can you do a `var_dump($_POST['arrinput']);` before the if condition. And there is no need to do `$_POST['arrinput']==NULL`. The empty function check if the var is different from : null, emty string, int/float equals to 0, FALSE, empty array.

Comment: you validating is already worked ! try input empty value `""`

Comment: @DavidJawphan No it's now working on my server it works on local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out thank you guys for help

```
foreach( $_POST['arrinput'] as $key => $value )
{
    if( empty( $value ) )
    {
      echo 'value is empaty';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['arrinput'])){
        die("value found!");
    }else{
        die("value not found!");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this check whether the $_POST['arrinput']
is  empty or not

```
<?php 

    if(empty($_POST['arrinput'])){
    echo 'value is empty';
    }
    else{
    for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
    echo '<input type="text" name="arrinput[]">';
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: there is no error .. it just not simply validating the array input

Comment: Ok wait let me post it what i was doing :)